# Settings vs Code: Can I turn off Broadcast Message through settings?

Tags: 7

I manage a [Drupal Commons](http://drupal.org/project/commons) site (that relies heavily on [OG](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)). I've a request to **turn off** the ability to broadcast to groups. Is there a box that somewhere that I can un-check or is it better to use `hook_menu_alter()` in a custom theme to disable the `og/users/%/invite` path?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can do this via `hook_menu_alter()`:

```
if (variable_get('custom_no_broadcast', true)) {
  unset($items['node/%/broadcast']);
}
```

And in I take the link out via `hook_preprocess_block()`:

```
// If set, attempts to surpess the link to broadcast messages to all group members.
if (variable_get('custom_no_broadcast', true)) {
    $variables['block']->content  = preg_replace("/<a\shref=\"\/node\/\d+\/broadcast\">Broadcast message<\/a>/", '', $variables['block']->
}
```

Or just turn off the Commons Notifications module.